# intellisense foreach not populating class correctly

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

As I type

`foreach (RegmapInputReader.BitField bf in RM.registerMapList){/*etc.*/}`

the intellisense recommendations for `RegmapInputReader.xxxxx` are wrong. If I manually type in BitField, there are some green lines under

`RegmapInputReader.`

After I complete the code, it is fine, it compiles and runs fine. Why is intellisense unable to help in this situation? Why can it not find my BitField class?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the XML file associated with the project that the class comes from is not up to date, or is not copied to the correct folder.  Intellisense uses the XML files created when projects are compiled